# kafka running in Docker logs: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory" when receiving payload from Github

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, github-api

We have in our production

## kafka --version

7.2.1-ccs (Commit:80334008361592c187b36a27536f10f33fe93aa3)
running in a docker Container

## java -version

- openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS, mixed
  mode)

this is the .yml for kafka docker container:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.2.1
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.1
    ports:
      - <some ip @>:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 2147483647
      KAFKA_Max_Direct_MemorySize
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xmx2G -Xms2G
```

I'm trying to send **github events** directly to a kafka topic via a gihub app **Webhook**.

to expose the kafka topic in dev mode I'm using ngrok.

ngrock receive a POST request from github, but the docker logs shows this:

```
ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at java.base/java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:175)
        at java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:118)
        at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:317)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Util.getTemporaryDirectBuffer(Util.java:242)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:242)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:356)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.read(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:103)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:118)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:1144)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:1047)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

when I tested it by sending a msg with postman it worked. I want to make it work with the github events payload.

for debugging purposes I removed all consumer of that topic.

**things I've tried:**

- increase docker resources and KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS to 12G
- setting the security protocol as [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4090?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA%20AND%20text%20%7E%20java.lang.OutOfMemoryError) post suggests by adding these to the .yml file:

```
      KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: 'required'
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: ssl.creds
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: ssl.creds
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: ssl.creds
      KAFKA_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.keystore.jks
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Kafka isn't an HTTP service. It doesn't accept webhooks. You do not need 12G to accept an HTTP request